# Setting a combined optionsText in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to combine two return values in my optionsText field, I thought this would be simple, but I am apparently wrong. I'm also using a value for the options field that is outside the normal view model.  Here is the original:

```
<select style="width: 180px" data-bind="visible: false, value: fields.person, options: $root.extra.personList, optionsText: 'FirstName', optionsValue: 'LastName' }, select2: {}">
```

This works fine, displays the person's FirstName and sets the value as LastName.

This next piece throws an error:

```
<select style="width: 180px" data-bind="visible: false, value: fields.person, options: $root.extra.personList, optionsText: function (item) { return item.FirstName() + '-' + item.LastName() }, optionsValue: 'LastName', select2: {}">
```

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'FirstName' of object # is not a function

Comment: You sure `FirstName` and `LastName` are observables? If you're not sure, try this: `ko.unwrap(item.FirstName) + '-' + ko.unwrap(item.LastName)`

Comment: I am not sure, I will try that out.

Comment: Before you start adding that into your view, consider moving that function into your view model and invoking it. It will lead to _much_ cleaner code.

Comment: @JeffMercado This, and make it a `ko.computed`.

Comment: Thanks sroes, I didn't manage the previous model so I didn't know they weren't observable. Could you make that an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: You guys are also correct that it would be cleaner to add the function  directly into the model.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You sure FirstName and LastName are observables? If you're not sure, try this:

```
optionsText: function(item) { return ko.unwrap(item.FirstName) + '-' + ko.unwrap(item.LastName); }
```

Or better yet, create a computed in your viewmodel:

```
self.FullName = function() {
    return ko.unwrap(self.FirstName) + '-' + ko.unwrap(self.LastName);
};
```

And:

```
optionsText: 'FullName'
```

Comment: @ChrisNevill I know your comment is 4 months old, but as a note to others, FullName must be a member of the option, not the viewmodel. http://jsfiddle.net/a1mjnczL/3/

Comment: Thanks Silvermind.  I guess I must have eventually come up with a solution but forgot to come back here.

Answer (score 0):

how optionsText works is it looks for the property 'FirstName' on the options array that is is bound to. So if your extra person array has a 'FirstName' and a 'LastName' you can extend a computed property to hold full name.

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this; 
    self.peopleList = ko.observableArray(); 
}
function Person(f, l){
    var self = this; 
    self.FirstName = ko.obserable(f); 
    self.LastName = ko.obserable(l); 
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.FirstName() + ' ' + self.LastName();
    });
}
```

If they are not observables you don't want to be calling them [ what () does ] it would in that case I would just have a function living on the view model that puts them together which  you call from the binding.