# Knockout bind select to dynamic observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've got a problem with dynamic binding to select control using knockout. What I want to achieve is a piece of code that binds the observableArray of observable objects to the select options. The 'objects' inside the observableArray change constantly.

The object stored in the observableArray, let's call it sampleObj, has a few properties (which are ko.observables) like name, lastName and phoneNumber. I would like to display as select options lastNames of all objects stored in the observableArray.

My binding to the observable inside the cshtml looks as follows:

```
<select data-bind="options: sampleObservableArray, optionsText: lastName, optionsCaption: 'choose...'"></select>
```

and it does not display anything besides the 'choose...' text. The content of the sampleObservableArray is updating in the js and I can console.log it whenever I want. Is there anything wrong in the way I bind the values or maybe should I somehow force refreshing of the select control?
Of course as a complete amateur, I have tried I think all possible combinations of using and not using parethnesis :) but still with no effect.

sampleObservableArray - ko.observableArray that contains sampleObj's

sampleObj - ko.observable with a few properties like name, lastName and phoneNumber where all are ko.observables as well.

**EDIT:**
Answering for @Tomalak's ask there is a code for better clarity. Firstly, sampleObj model:

```
define('sampleObj',
['ko'],
function (ko) {
    var
        SampleObj = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.name = ko.observable();
            self.lastName = ko.observable();
            self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();
            return self;
        };

    return SampleObj;
});
```

then adding the sampleObj objects to the observableArray:

```
// newData is an argument of a function triggered by signalR action, and returns strings as its properties
var sampleObj = ko.observable(new SampleObj()
    .name(newData.name)
    .lastName(newData.lastName)
    .phoneNumber(newData.phoneNumber);

var sampleObjEntry = ko.utils.arrayFirst(sampleObservableArray(), function (item) {
    return item().phoneNumber() === newData.phoneNumber;
});
// if object with the phoneNumber already exits replace it, if not - add
if (!sampleObjEntry) {
    sampleObservableArray.push(sampleObj);
} else {
    sampleObservableArray()[sampleObservableArray().indexOf(sampleObjEntry)] = sampleObj;
    sampleObservableArray.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Don't know if it helps.

Comment: Instead of lengthily *describing* how your data model is structured, how about simply showing a sample? It would make things much easier for everybody. Maybe even set up a jsFiddle. (Besides, the `optionsText:` binding is supposed to be a string)

Comment: @Tomalak the `optionsText` binding also works [with a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388199/setting-a-combined-optionstext-in-knockout-js)

Comment: @GôTô Yes, I know. By the OP's description however, I would have expected to see `'lastName'` there, not `lastName()`. In this case a *function result* is used, which could be anything and not necessarily refer to a property on any object in `sampleObservableArray`. So I tend to say it's an error.

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed! Even though it's hard to say given the little code we have

Comment: Like I suspected. Use `optionsText: 'lastName'`. (Hint: You're telling knockout the *name* of the property it should use.) Also - why are you wrapping `SampleObj` in another observable? That should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, changed that, but still does not display anything on the list. I see why it should be without parenthesis, you're right.
Tbh the in-between observable is just a result of long fights with the problem. I've seen somewhere that someone uses it like that and just tried. Without that observable still no effects however :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created simple [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZF63/)*, and it works as expected.
I think the problem in your code is in line

```
sampleObservableArray()[sampleObservableArray().indexOf(sampleObjEntry)] = sampleObj;
```

You should remove `sampleObjEntry` from array and then push `sampleObj` or update already existent `sampleObjEntry`.

*For example:*

```
...
else {
    sampleObjEntry.name(newData.name);
    sampleObjEntry.lastName(newData.lastName);
    sampleObjEntry.phoneNumber(newData.phoneNumber);
}
```

or

```
....
else {
    sampleObservableArray.remove(sampleObjEntry);
    sampleObservableArray.push(sampleObj);
}
```

*JSFiddle demo source

**Javascript**

```
function Person(name, lastName, phone)
{
    return {
        name : ko.observable(name),
        lastName : ko.observable(lastName),
        phoneNumber : ko.observable(phone)
    }
}

var vm = {
    sampleObservableArray : ko.observableArray(),
    addPerson : function()
    {
       var newPhone = document.getElementById("_phone").value,
           newName = document.getElementById("_name").value,
           newLastName = document.getElementById("_lastName").value;
       var existentPerson = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.sampleObservableArray(), function(item)
                                                {
                                                    return item.phoneNumber() == newPhone;
                                                })
       if (existentPerson)
       {
           existentPerson.name(newName);
           existentPerson.lastName(newLastName);
           existentPerson.phoneNumber(newPhone);
       }
       else
       {
           vm.sampleObservableArray.push(new Person(newName, newLastName, newPhone))
       }


    }
}

vm.sampleObservableArray.push(new Person("Ronald", "McDonald", "1"))
vm.sampleObservableArray.push(new Person("Michael", "McConnel", "2"))

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

**Html**

```
<select data-bind="options: sampleObservableArray, optionsText: 'lastName', optionsCaption: 'choose...'"></select>  
<br/>
<label for="_name">Name:</label><input id="_name"/><br/>
<label for="_lastName">Last Name:</label><input id="_lastName"/><br/>
<label for="_phone">Phone:</label><input id="_phone"/><br/>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add person</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your ansewer! I have replaced my code with yours but still no success. Even though, without those improvements, I believe that in my code at first new value should be added and displayed on the dropdown but it is not.

What is more, thank you for your fiddle. I have changed it a bit so that the button will add a new entry to the observableArray buuut it does not work! Maybe I make some mistakes there? Could you please look on it?

http://jsfiddle.net/qyQ36/1/

Comment: Eh, thanks, that was silly, I hoped that I found my problem there.