# Knockout binding to Select optionsText to get fullName

Tags: knockout.js

Question is regarding optionsText binding to get fullName.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/4/)

When I do this it works [as in Knockout doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html),

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: leftItems,optionsText: function(item) {return item.firstName() + ' ' + item.lastName() }, selectedOptions:leftSelectedItems"></select>
```

But when I move the function to View Model and try to use it does not work,

Here is my select,

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: leftItems,optionsText: returnFullName(item), selectedOptions:leftSelectedItems"></select>
```

In my View Model,

```
    self.returnFullName = function(item) {
        console.log("self.returnFullName called.");
        console.log(item);
        return item.firstName() + ' ' + item.lastName();
    };
```

Error I am getting is that "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return leftItems }" which is even not related to optionText.

Am I missing something?

Comment: the actual error you are getting is : Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return names }"
Message: item is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a combined optionsText in knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388199/setting-a-combined-optionstext-in-knockout-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass it as you do. But you can follow any of these methods.

- Method1

You can just call the viewmodel function and the first parameter will implicitly have the $data parameter.

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="150" data-bind="options: names,optionsText: returnFullName"></select>
```

and in VM

```
 self.returnFullName = function(item) {
     console.log(item);
        return item.firstName + " " + item.lastName;

    };
```

Jsfiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/10/

- Method 2

Bind the $data and pass it as you do.

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="150" data-bind="options: names,optionsText:returnFullName.bind($data);"></select>
```

Jsfiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/42/

- Method 3:-

You can wrap it in a function call and call like this:-

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="150" data-bind="options: names,optionsText:function(data){ return returnFullName(data);}"></select>
```

Jsfiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/51/